Why Won't My Gradient Work on SVG graphic?
I'm trying to make a gradient on this svg graphic but is not working. In the material preview I can see that I made this in the right way.


Hello please share your file

try using object coordinates and play around with the mapping values (scale and x location):


I changed to your settings and it worked, thank you

you are welcome
